# Selenium get HTML (or JSON) response from WebDriver

Tags: java, ajax, json, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code but its not working

```
public static String getHTMLResponse(String url){
   String body = (String) js.executeScript("$.ajax({url:\""+ url + "\", success:function(result){ return result;}});");
    return body;
}
```

For some reason this is always returning null.

Has anyone tried to get a CURL response from ajax in webdriver? I was doing this in java before but I am getting certificate errors constantly and just want something more reliable.

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so Jason Smiley posted a solution but without an explanation as to what the problem was and how the solution works.

The first problem is that the script passed to `executeScript` does not return anything, period. What `executeScript` does is wrap the script you pass to it in `function () { ... }`. So something of the form `$.ajax(...)` would be executed as this in the browser:

```
function () {
    $.ajax(...);
}
```

This obviously won't return anything in the same way that if the script were `2 + 2` it would not return `4` because it would execute as:

```
function () {
    2 + 2;
}
```

The script passed to `executeScript` would have to be `return 2 + 2`.

However, here, just adding this `return` won't fix the problem. There is an additional problem that `$.ajax` is an asynchronous function. When `$.ajax` executes, it *returns right away*. The functions that are passed to it are stored for *future* execution. If `$.ajax` returns right away, then the value it returns cannot *possibly* be the return value of any of the functions that are given to it because these have not executed *yet*. Conversely, then the functions passed to `$.ajax` do execute, whatever they give to `return` cannot be retrieved by *your* code. The only thing you can do is use the values you care about inside of the function itself or pass it to another function.

The solution is to use `executeAsyncScript` which is designed for asynchronous execution. This function is just like `executeScript` but adds an argument which is a callback which should be called when the script has finished executing and it should be called with the value you want `executeAsyncScript` to return.

Note that it is absolutely not necessary to abandon `$.ajax`. The following should work:

```
public static String getHTMLResponse(String url){
    String body = (String) js.executeAsyncScript(
        "var url = arguments[0];" + 
        "var callback = arguments[1];" +
        "$.ajax({url: url, success: callback});", 
        url);
    return body;
}
```

Note that I've set this code so that `url` is passed as an argument instead of being concatenated into the script. I find this cleaner than concatenation. In case this needs be explained, `arguments` is an object automatically made available by the JavaScript virtual machine. It holds the list of arguments given to a function.

Whether `$.ajax` is used or `XMLHttpRequest` is used directly the principles are the same.

Comment: Thanks Louis! I didn't mention this in the ticket, but I actually had a few variations of the OP script. I could tell that nothing was being returned, I guess I didn't know WHY nothing was being returned. For instance, why does "success: callback" work and not "success: return arguments[1]" or "success: function(){return arguments[1]}". Pretty sure one of these didn't compile but I can't remember which lol

Answer (score 1):

A front end developer gave me the script!

```
   public static String getHTMLResponse(String url){
      String body = (String) js.executeAsyncScript(
            "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];" +
                    "var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();" +
                    "xhr.open('GET', '"+ url + "', true);" +
                    "xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {" +
                    "  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {" +
                    "    callback(xhr.responseText);" +
                    "  }" +
                    "};" +
                    "xhr.send();");
      return body;
  }
```

Comment: Not anymore actually - I had to change it. Will add a new answer